# Any tips for mutating the state using redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutability, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux-toolkit and React.
I know basic redux (not using redux-toolkit) aren't allowed to mutate the original state. That's why I chose redux-toolkit to be able to do it. However,I can't understand what's a forbidden way to mutate the state using redux-toolkit. I read an offical document below but it didn't work to me.

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers

Especially Immer Usage Patterns in the document.What's the difference between Mutating and Returning state and Resetting and Replacing state? It looks like similar. Plus, I can't figure out Updating Nested Data in the document.

could you tell me any tips for using redux-toolkit?

Answer (score 2):

The intro of the page you've linked to effectively covers a bit of history for how Redux reducer functions worked in that past. Redux state is considered to be immutable, so if you wanted to update any part of a slice's state you necessarily needed to shallow copy all state and nested state that you wanted to update.

See [Reducers and Immutable State](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#reducers-and-immutable-updates):

> ```
> function handwrittenReducer(state, action) {
>   return {
>     ...state,
>     first: {
>       ...state.first,
>       second: {
>         ...state.first.second,
>         [action.someId]: {
>           ...state.first.second[action.someId],
>           fourth: action.someValue,
>         },
>       },
>     },
>   }
> }
> ```

Redux-Toolkit comes with immer baked right in, so we can write mutable reducer functions and know we are only editing a draft copy of the state that will get applied in an immutable way.

You are interested in the [Immer Usage Patterns](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#immer-usage-patterns), specifically [Mutating and Returning State](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#mutating-and-returning-state).

> In any given case reducer, **Immer expects that you will either *mutate*
> the existing state, or construct a new state value yourself and return
> it, but *not* both in the same function!** For example, both of these are
> valid reducers with Immer:
>
> ```
> const todosSlice = createSlice({
>   name: 'todos',
>   initialState: [],
>   reducers: {
>     todoAdded(state, action) {
>       // "Mutate" the existing state, no return value needed
>       state.push(action.payload)
>     },
>     todoDeleted(state, action.payload) {
>       // Construct a new result array immutably and return it
>       return state.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.payload)
>     }
>   }
> })
> ```

You can either **mutate** a part of the state and the change will be correctly applied ***or*** you can **return** an entirely new state object with as much or as little of it updated as you need. The only thing that is forbidden is to mutate part of the existing state ***and*** return a new state object reference.

### Forbidden update:

```
const todosSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState: {todos: [], status: 'idle'}
  reducers: {
    todoDeleted(state, action.payload) {
      // Construct a new array immutably
      const newTodos = state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.payload);

      // "Mutate" the existing state to save the new array
      state.todos = newTodos;

      return {
        ...state,
        status: 'complete',
      };
    }
  }
});
```

### Acceptable update:

```
const todosSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState: {todos: [], status: 'idle'}
  reducers: {
    todoDeleted(state, action.payload) {
      // Construct a new array immutably
      const newTodos = state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.payload);

      // "Mutate" the existing state to save the new array
      state.todos = newTodos;
      state.status = 'complete';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Drew! Your explanation helps me understand redux-toolkit with immer.